# Is it possible to get random values using ArrayHelper? Yii2

Tags: php, mysql, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

How do I get random values from another table? In my employee php I have 3 records, so there is 3 id values. In my ticket.php once I create a ticket it will automatically get the id value from the employee table but it is not randomise how do I do it?

Mine is currently getting the same value from employee whenever I create a ticket.

In the ticketcontroller.php

```
 public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Ticket();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    } else {
        $model->time_start = date('y-m-d h:i:s');
        $model->status = ('On Going');
        $model->employee_respond_id = array_rand('id');
        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

In the _form.php

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'employee_respond_id')->dropDownlist(
                                ArrayHelper::map(Employee::find()->all(), 'id', 'id'),
                                [
                                    'readOnly' => true,
                                    'style' => 'width:200px'
                                ]
); ?>
```

Comment: `array_rand` should be given the array you want to get a random value of. [array_rand](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php)

Comment: Yes, I already tried it $model->employee_respond_id = array_Rand('id', 'id');
but I'm getting an error "array_rand() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given" Can you give me a clue why is it wrong?

Comment: does `'id', 'id'` appear as an array to you?

Comment: Oh sorry, I just read the php documentation I was wrong here I didn't noticed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way:

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Ticket();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    } else {
        $employeeIDs = ArrayHelper::map(Employee::find()->all(), 'id', 'id'),
        $model->time_start = date('y-m-d h:i:s');
        $model->status = ('On Going');
        $model->employee_respond_id = array_rand($employeeIDs);
        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
            'employeeIDs' => $employeeIDs
        ]);
    }
}
```

**_form.php**

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'employee_respond_id')->dropDownlist(
    $employeeIDs,
    [
       'readOnly' => true,
        'style' => 'width:200px'
    ]
); ?>
```

Better use employee name as label and id as value in dropdown, still it will work for random function.

Comment: Oh I get it now, so I need to set the arrayhelper first "$employeeIDs = ArrayHelper::map(Employee::find()->all(), 'id', 'id')," before I use the array_rand function